# What's the state of an activity of video application when it's in split screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-state

I'm setting up an application in Android with capability of working in split screen. What is the state (in activity life-cycle) of my activity when it's visible but not in interaction with user? It is notable that, the activity is responsible for playing video.

Comment: You can check the lifecycle here as the user @dustblue referred : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window#lifecycle

Otherwise you can always use logging in lifecycle functions and see the flow yourself .